# Capybara ingore `within` scope at specify assertion

Tags: capybara, system-testing

Suppose I'm testing a form with Capybara and Minitest, the form has a text input, which using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#container), I wanna unscope(like ActiveRecord) the within('form') scope only at `assert_selector '.datepicker-dropdown', count: 1`, as `.datepicker-dropdown` is appended to body not the form

```
within "form" do
  # other tests...
  find("input.date-picker").click
  assert_selector '.datepicker-dropdown', count: 1 
  # failed because .datepicker-dropdown is appended to body
end
```

Though bootstrap-datepicker have an option [container](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#container) to specify where to append the datepicker-dropdown widget, but not suitable for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of escaping the scope of `within`. The first would be to use XPath and taking advantage of the Xpath-trap (https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap) by intentionally breaking the scope

```
assert_xpath '//*', class: 'datepicker-dropdown', count: 1
```

The second (and probably clearer) method would be to use the `page.document` method to escape the current scope

```
assert_selector page.document, '.datepicker-dropdown', count: 1
```